# Make account delete itself on poweroff

Tags: accounts

I need a way to create an account that will delete itself when the system does a full poweroff, but not on a reboot or logout.  It also needs to have a unique account name (not guest) and password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo adduser newuser
```

It will ask for password of newuser.

Create a bash script, for example: `deleteuser.sh`

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
deluser --remove-all-files newuser
```

**To execute a script at shutdown**

- Put your script in `/etc/rc0.d`
- Make it executable (`sudo chmod +x deleteuser.sh`)
- Note: The scripts in this directory are executed in alphabetical
  order

Comment: Good one, but I would have asked an additional question: what needs to be done with the files that the user created?  and then do a --delete-home or --delete-allfiles (or maybe nothing like you proposed!) ;-)

Comment: @Fabby I updated answer. Thx!

Comment: I made a correction in answer. Dİrectory should be `/etc/rc0.d`

Comment: I actually just discovered that there are some rather stringent naming conventions for scripts in the run level folders.  Specifically, they are required to start with 'K99' and not have an extension. Could you update your answer with these to save future readers a little frustration?